# How to create custom reference data for ColorChecker Charts using X-Rite ColorChecker Camera Calibration?

Tags: color-management, colorchecker

I am using [ColorChecker Camera Calibration v2.0](https://xritephoto.com/ph_product_overview.aspx?ID=938&Action=Support&SoftwareID=2030) in combination with Colorchecker Digital SG achieving the most colourimetric accurate colours. At the moment the software is using the values given by the ColorChecker manufacturer (X-Rite). But I have profiled all the patches of the target using a colourimeter and I would like to use those values instead. I can't find a way to do that searching on the internet. Is there any way I can access and modify the reference values of the targets?

If you are not used to scientific photography please read the description of why I need this at the following [link](https://www.xrite.com/service-support/how_to_create_custom_reference_data_for_colorchecker_charts_using_i1profiler) [(archived copy)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170914085658/https://www.xrite.com/service-support/how_to_create_custom_reference_data_for_colorchecker_charts_using_i1profiler). My question is simply: how can I do that with  **ColorChecker Camera Calibration** software instead of i1Profiler as I do now.

Comment: When you say, "for calibrating my images" exactly what do you mean? Calibrating so that the colors output by your printer are as close to possible to the colors you see on your screen? Calibrating so that a photo of a "white" or "neutral gray" object appears "white" or "neutral gray" on your screen? Calibrating your screen so that a white or neutral grey screen output appears white or neutral gray to your eyes in the viewing environment you are in? Creating a camera profile?

Comment: Re: "values given by the manufacturer". What manufacturer? Of the camera? X-Rite? Your monitor? Your printer?

Comment: @MichaelC thanks for your feedback I have updated the question for making it more clear. In photography sometimes color tagets can be used for achieving more accurate images these target are used for creating profiles based on color of some reference patches

Comment: @G M You're still assuming I can tell which step in the image processing chain you have in mind. If you are trying to create camera color profiles, that really can't be described as "calibrating your images" so much as it can be described as calibrating your raw conversion software's demosaicing algorithms to match your camera's color response characteristics.

Comment: I'm still wondering a) how you establish that the colorimeter is more accurate than the swatches & b) how 'differently' describing the swatches will aid final output.

Comment: @MichaelC why not? I think that's the definition of calibrate something. The question is not related to any specific step, but on the process of creating DNG and ICC profiles.

Comment: @Tetsujin a) the colorimeter is certified over NIST traceable standards. b) the LAB values provided by the manufacturers are an average of the values recorded and they are not relative to the sample neither to the batch. The printing has always some difference in the nuances, furthermore aging of the standard requires new characterization of the samples.

Comment: I think your question would be improved by: 1. Describing the reasons the manufacturer's values are unsuitable for your purpose; 2. Describing the variations of the colorimeter's values from the manufacturer's values; 3. Describing how you determined the manufacturer's values. These will help because it is non-obvious how to help you without some context. Particularly because the X-rite color checker system is a photographic industry standard with a long track record. Designed to work with most photographic workflows. Designed to solve photographic problems. There's a clear one described here.

Comment: *Profiling* and *Calibrating*, though similar, are two distinct things. And when you are *profiling* a system you are not "calibrating images", you're "profiling your system". In a very real sense, it's impossible to "calibrate an image". One can calibrate and profile a system so that images display correctly.

Comment: Your prints will never *perfectly* match your screen, This is because there are some colors the screen is capable of producing that the printer isn't and vice-versa. One uses additive color, the other uses subtractive color. Screens emit light. Prints reflect light.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens thanks  if you need more information you may have a look here https://www.xrite.com/service-support/how_to_create_custom_reference_data_for_colorchecker_charts_using_i1profiler this explain why I need to use measured values.  If I write all this the question will be too verbose, my question is very clear and ask simly how can I add new reference values to the software. The motivation I do that are not important.

Comment: @MichaelC "Calibration is a comparison between a known measurement (the standard) and the measurement using your instrument." this is what I am doing with my images I have got UKAS certified reference materials and I compute Delta E for each patch. I know the limitations of color reproduction, but what I do is to try to limit the error as much as I can. I am doing scientific imaging not hobby photography.

Comment: So than where is the known image to which you are calibrating your image? To "calibrate" an image, you are trying to make a second copy of the image match the first. You're not trying to calibrate images here. You're trying to profile your system so that it accurately reproduces colors. You can dig in your heels and insist that it's obvious what you re doing to "calibrate your image" and never get an answer because no one will understand what you're asking. Or you can more clearly describe the process you're doing and get an answer.

Comment: @MichaelC Ok thanks, I removed the word calibrate from the question. I use photos of reference standard with known Lab values by UKAS and GoldenThread,bytheway, but this is not important. My question is simple now I copyied the format of X-rite see the answer to their similar question to understand.

Comment: "Scientific photography" may be outside the scope of this site.  It seems the sofware you are using does not support the features you desire.  Have you tried contacting the developers?

Comment: @xiota yeah I am sorry, I thought it could be helpful for others to know, but this is probably too advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The manufacture (X-Rite) provides instructions on their site. This link might be helpful. https://www.xrite.com/-/media/xrite/files/apps_engineering_techdocuments/c/custom_reference_data_en.pdf

Further information may be available from X-Rite staff. Contacting them is recommended if public facing information is inadequate.

Comment: Thanks but this it is only for i1Profiler software and is what I am doing now(see question), but you can't build DNG profiles.